# Automatically adding dimensions to polygons in QGIS

Tags: qgis, dimensions

Is it possible to show :

- lot #
- area
- dimensions of the polygon's lines
- highlighted polygon

with the only input being the lot #. The result should look like this:[image]

Comment: Are you creating an atlas?

Comment: I want to add visual information on a map that contains about 600 000 lots, so it has to be done automatically. Any ideas?

Comment: The area is easy, label with `$area`. For the dimension you can try using the geometry generator: https://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=sv&tl=en&u=https%3A%2F%2Fgeosupportsystem.se%2F2018%2F11%2F01%2Fhaftig-geometrigenerator%2F&sandbox=1 . Probably tricky when you have some curved lines

Comment: Look also at https://github.com/faunalia/QGIS-Resources/tree/master/collections/distance-measurements (to grasp the idea, look at preview dir). Content also available via "QGIS Resource Sharing" plugin